# JQuery Validation - How do I detect '&' keyPress ( allow only '&' not '7', coz for both keycode is '55')

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want a validation which allows '&' keypress but not a numeric key '7', How do I do that.
    Following is my code snippet ...

```
    $(function(){
        $('#idCategoryName').keydown(function(event){
            var keyCode = event.keyCode;
            var categoryName = $('#idCategoryName').val();
            /* console.log("'"+ ( categoryName.slice(1) == " " ) +"' "+ categoryName.slice(1)); */
            /* console.log(keyCode); */
            if( keyCode == 32 ) {
                if( ( categoryName.slice(-1) == " ") )
                    event.preventDefault();
                if( event.target.selectionStart === 0)
                    return false;
            }
            if( keyCode == 55 )
                if( ( categoryName.slice(-1) == "&") )
                    event.preventDefault();
            if( keyCode == 191 )
                if( ( categoryName.slice(-1) == "/" ) )
                    event.preventDefault();             
            return ( ( keyCode >= 65 && keyCode <= 90 ) || keyCode == 8 || keyCode == 9 || 
                        keyCode == 37 || keyCode == 38 || keyCode == 39 || keyCode == 40 || 
                            keyCode == 32 || keyCode == 13 || keyCode == 46 || keyCode == 55 || 
                                keyCode == 191 );
        });
    });
```

This code allows '7' to be entered , and I dont want any numeric value to my inputbox , code improvemet, welcome...

**My Updated, working snippet ...**

```
    $(function(){
        $('#idCategoryName').keydown(function(event){
            var keyCode = event.keyCode;
            var categoryName = $('#idCategoryName').val();
            /* console.log("'"+ ( categoryName.slice(1) == " " ) +"' "+ categoryName.slice(1)); */
            /* console.log(keyCode); */
            if( keyCode == 32 ) {
                if( ( categoryName.slice(-1) == " ") )
                    event.preventDefault();
                if( event.target.selectionStart === 0)
                    return false;
            }
             **Changed Here**
            if( event.shiftKey ) {
                if( ( categoryName.slice(-1) == "&") )
                    event.preventDefault();
                if( keyCode == 55 ) 
                        return true;
            }
            if( keyCode == 191 )
                if( ( categoryName.slice(-1) == "/" ) )
                    event.preventDefault();             
            return ( ( keyCode >= 65 && keyCode <= 90 ) || keyCode == 8 || keyCode == 9 || 
                        keyCode == 37 || keyCode == 38 || keyCode == 39 || keyCode == 40 || 
                            keyCode == 32 || keyCode == 13 || keyCode == 46 || keyCode == 191 );
        });
    });
```

Comment: You need to detect the `shift` key too, to check if that button/key is pressed.

Comment: the best and simple(i would say simpler and clean) solution for this is REGEX pattern matching, since you are inputting it to text box, why dont you bind a `change` event and do pattern matching!

Comment: @ShekharPankaj , thanks for suggestion I'll try and let u know....

Comment: @C0dekid.php I detect shiftKey using event, event.shiftKey, then check keyCode with 55, n it works ...
thank u..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to detect the `shift` key too. Then put that in an `if` statement.

*based on your code*

Example:

```
if(event.shiftKey == true && keyCode == 55) {
    alert("Shift + 7 (&) are pressed!");
}
```

The keyCode for `shift` is `16`.

Example on fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/C0dekid/dprx94j7/

Comment: ur code still returns true if only key '7' is pressed , remove 'keyCode == 55' from last return... in jsfiddle

Comment: I see, trying to figure it out for you now :) @shantaram

Answer (score 0):

You can use event.shiftKey.
if event.shiftKey is false then Shift is not down

```
 if (!event.shiftKey && keyCode == 55)      
    event.preventDefault();
```